# Ground loop from 2.1 speakers plugged into same circuit

Tags: audio, power, speakers

I've got a set of 2.1 speakers with a 2-prong power cord.  I have a desktop pc, couple monitors, and the speakers all plugged into the same power strip.  The power strip is a 3-pronger.  The computer is not connected to anything else - no ethernet, nothing.

When I plug the audio jack into the audio port on the motherboard, I get a low bass hum from the subwoofer.  When I unplug it from the computer (speakers still powered though), it goes away.

First - that's a ground loop, right?  But how could it be with everything going to the same outlet?  I have also tried plugging the speaker power into a separate outlet, and another on a different circuit in the building.  No change.

Second, how might I mitigate this?  I've tried plugging the speakers into several other outlets, including in the other room (though I'm not certain it's actually a different circuit).  No change.

Edit: more information.  The hum is present if I touch the 3.5mm jack to the metal of the case, or even touch the tip of the plug with a finger.  I'm not moving the cable at all - finger on, hum.  Finger off, nothing.  That suggests to me *not* EMI, correct?

Edit 2: touching the tip of the plug with a finger creates a hum.  Also touching (ring only, ring+sleeve, sleeve only) with a wet finger - no change.  That is, the hum continues.

Comment: What you describe is closer to `Electromagnetic interference (EMI)` then a ground loop.  A capacitor that isn't behaving itself would be a form of EMI, so my intial thought, is confirmed by Tetsujin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not that you misunderstand 'ground loop' it's that you're assuming it's a ground loop when the laptop is almost certainly not wired to Earth [US ground] by design.
*[edit, confirmation that it's a desktop with earthed induction-coil power-supply now makes my first guess unlikely, but read on...]*

If the speakers run on an external power-supply, then neither are they. *[edit, 2-prong power cord you said - sorry, I come from a country where they don't exist... missed that one] so it's definitely not earthed [US grounded]*

Your prime suspects then become a floating ground offset, caused by capacitive leakage on one or more of the power-supplies, or even just poor connections on the cabling.

Things to test...

1. new cable.
2. laptop running on only battery.

*Edit 2:*
Confirmation that the hum does not disappear when the ground terminal is touched together with the signal hot makes the greatest possibility the cable itself.

[I'm using UK terminology for 'earth' rather than the US one 'ground' because earth differentiates from 'signal ground' in audio circuits, whereas the US 'ground' does not.

Comment: It's a desktop, not a laptop, if that matters.  Surely *that* power supply is earthed, right?

Comment: If it onlyhas two prongs going to the wall socket it is not.  Even if it does have 3-prongs, the ground would only be accurate, if the wiring is correct.  *You can convert a 2-prong to a 3-prong and not have an accurate ground.*

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  The PC power supply has 3 prongs, plugged into the power strip which has 3 prongs, plugged into a 3-prong wall socket.  Edit: I updated the question with a little more info.

Comment: I recall from the depths of time some people taking a decent gauge speaker wire, putting lugs on the ends and attaching one lug to the outlet cover screw of a grounded outlet, and attaching the other lug to a metal part of the frame of the equipment which only had a two-prong plug. Is this acceptable or is it dangerous? I don't really know.

Comment: Actually, as I'd assumed laptop that does slightly change things. A desktop is more likely to have a large coil-wound transformer rather than a small switch-mode supply - it also **really** ought to be Earthed, as you've clarified, it is. Your clarifications actually are making it sound more like the cable - try this & post another edit... grasp just the tip of the plug to make it hum, then with a **wet** finger grasp the plug casing &/or 'ring' if the case is plastic. If the hum disappears the cable is fine & we need to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Yorik - You shouldn't do that.  While unsafe it won't solve the problem.  The EMI is effecting the subwoofer not the case.  Besides this would be no difference then connecting the ground, to the powerstrip though, with a cable.  I purchased a 30 outlet powerstrip that required you do that.  If the outlet is properly wired already that should already be acomplished with the use of a 3-prong plug.

Comment: Something I forgot to ask - you did check the plug has the correct number of rings to match the socket?? Definitely just tip, two rings & that's what the socket is expecting? Standard PC socket colours would be the green with that configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound: just to clarify (" Besides this would be no difference than connecting the ground to the powerstrip"), I meant on 2-prong equipment which only has hot and neutral. Again, I make no claims about safety, I just recall home audio setups where someone did this to eliminate hum, but that was...1977? 1978?

Comment: Plug is green tip ring sleeve, as shown here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Audio-TRS-Mini-Plug.jpg  Socket is the green port in my motherboard.  Updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: @Yorik - What you describe was basically how you installed the powerstrip  I purchased.  So it is indeed safe.  I returned it for the 3-prong connector though because you literally lost the outlet with the other model.

Comment: I still can't be absolutely certain, but the greatest possibility is that the signal ground is not continuous in the cable itself. [Sorry, this is one of those situations where if I was in the room, I could fix it inside 5 minutes - by interweb chat, it's a whole lot harder to nail down ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin what you're saying is the ground wire is broken somewhere in the audio cable?

Comment: @Wiscocrew - Its not broken per say, its more ground isn't as close to 0 Ohms, as it should.  Its high enough that your speakers are picking up the noise on the line.  the noise is the voltage occliations that are leaking.

Comment: that's my guess - but can't be certain. As @Ramhound says, something, somewhere, isn't correctly providing signal ground. Cable is the first place to test, but it may be internal to the audio amp. really hard to tell without being there. your touching the 'live' side of the circuit opens up the entire structure to EMI, 'closing' the circuit by also touching the ground should prevent it... very hard to tell where that apparent break is.